# Flash drive download for another computer?

Tags: flash

How do I download Ubuntu so that I may install it on another computer that presently does not have an operating system?

Comment: You'll, obviously, need a working computer with a working OS, to download Ubuntu, and make a bootable USB drive. You could also [buy a USB drive](https://www.osdisc.com/products/ubuntu/usb) with Ubuntu.

Comment: I am on that working computer and wish to download to this laptop

Comment: I am downloading it and will copy it to a flash drive as a bootable disc.  Then I will install Win XP and then Win 7

Comment: In that case, check out https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop.